# Nontrivial Gauss-Manin connection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Suppose $p: X \rightarrow S$ is a fiber bundle of smooth manifold, if the Gauss-Manin connection is nontrivial, could $p$ be trivial bundle as smooth manifold? Also, could $p$ be trivial bundle as topological manifold?

The case I am interested most is when $X$ and $S$ are complex manifolds. Feel free to restrict to this case if it is easier.

Comment: No. If $p$ is a trivial bundle (topologically), the flat bundle $R^ip_*(\mathbb{C})$ is trivial, and so is the Gauss-Manin connection.